# I am trying to display first column in the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

- I am trying to download the file from the grid.

  - when I click open first window link a popup opens.
  - in that popup you will see a grid with two columns.
  - but right now you dont see the first column
  - I am trying to download the file like the sample prototype fiddle.
  - can you guys tell me how to fix it providing my code below

sample prototype
http://jsfiddle.net/khfL1jsh/

need to fix in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wL4v15vd/2/

```or-tag-here
template: function csvDownload() {
    //return "testing" + that.FinancialDocuments.ImageType(model);
    var htmlString = "<a id=\'sportsDataPlayer\' download=\'download.csv\' type=\'text\/csv\'>#= FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf('/')+1) #</a>"
    var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
    var data = new Blob([csv]);
    var a2 = document.getElementById("sportsDataPlayer");
    alert("I am here");
    a2.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this is finally what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/wL4v15vd/9/

```
columns: [{
      field: "FileName",
      title: "File Name",

      template: function csvDownload(ev) {
        //return "testing" + that.FinancialDocuments.ImageType(model);
        var csv = "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n";
        var data = new Blob([csv]);
        var a = $('<a/>', {
          class: 'sportsDataPlayer',
          download: 'download.csv',
          type: 'text/csv',
          href: URL.createObjectURL(data),
          html: ev.FileName
        });
        return a[0].outerHTML;
      }
    }, {
      field: "ThreeDots",
      title: "Last Name",
      template: "<span class='deleteRow'>ThreeDots</span>"
    }]
```

Of course to explain, first problem you had is that you were having bad brackets, after that you were using id's - same id's on one page is very bad practice (id needs to be unique per element), also you were selecting elements before they were rendered on page. To get around this I added element creation on the fly and store in variable - now jquery is creating  element and assigning object on it - object properties are same as putting attributes on html element. To get FileName we pass parameter to template function and read it from there. In the end since you defined function for template we need to return  with outerHTML which actually contains entire  element for example:

```
<a class="sportsDataPlayer" download="download.csv" type="text/csv" href="blob:http://fiddle.jshell.net/8b53b8de-d0e1-40a5-b40f-0d9e3221915a">2 Download CSV (via btoa)</a>
```

Comment: still I am not able to download the css file...providing your fiddle here and I am seeing this error VM282:191 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null    http://jsfiddle.net/pegla/wL4v15vd/5/

Comment: hey I am getting null at this line I put a debugger...any idea how to get value here var a2 = document.getElementById("sportsDataPlayer");     http://jsfiddle.net/ohhrvopp/

Comment: Yeah because I returned wrong thing, but your problem is that you're setting multiple id's, I changed it to class now and should be okay but you still need to work out some things there: http://jsfiddle.net/wL4v15vd/6/

Comment: but still I am not able to download...can you tell me how to download...

Comment: can you tell me what was the problem and how you fixed it...so that in future I can fix it myself....

Comment: updated answer with explanation let me know if you have troubles understanding, key thing is $('<a/>',{...}) which will create new object every time template function is called and setting everything in object and then render it on page.

Comment: can't we retrive FileName from data array in the grid...since I need to display values from the grid

Comment: Added that as well, just had to pass in parameters, also added bit more description

Comment: hey when we download the document is it possible to open the document in a new window by default....can it be achieved...??

Comment: I don't think that is possible, since you're not opening document at all, you're just downloading it,.

Comment: can you skip the document download and directly open

Comment: That action is up to browser, if browser has a plugin for opening csv files and that plugin is set to open automatically then they will open it, if not then there is no chance to do that, default action from browser is 'save file' beside you don't want to implement solutions that work only for only some users. Anyway this thread is getting bit big I think my answer will fix problem you asked about, if you have more questions post new question about that.

Comment: Hey one more question is it possible to show documents like Google drive... like they show in New tab

Comment: As I said try posting another question, but it's highly unlikely that it will possible as it depends on multiple things like browser settings, operating system, applications installed...